# (Java) Use for loop to get all combinations and add to ArrayList, but ArrayList only have the last add one

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, arraylist

I have had a problem when I am doing my java program. I want to generate all the possible combinations of the element in a String array, and store each possible one into an overall ArrayList.

I used a for loop to go through all the possible combinations and use ArrayList.add to add each String array. However, when I was trying to print out the ArrayList to check, it only have the last String array at all the positions.

If I move the `System.out.println` to the inside of for loop, everything looks just fine. If I move the print to the outsides the loop, it just show that I only have the same String array at all positions.

Problem related to two parts of code:

```
String[] inputs = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"};
    int maxLength = 4;

    //Get the total number of all combinations with replacement, used for the for loop
    int total = (int) Math.pow(inputs.length, maxLength);

    ArrayList<String[]> allList = new ArrayList<>();

    System.out.println(total);

    String[] subSets = new String[maxLength];
    int [] index = new int [maxLength];
    Arrays.fill(index, 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < total; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < maxLength; j++)
        {
            subSets[j] = inputs[index[j]];
        }
        allList.add(i, subSets);
        if (i != (total - 1))
            index = nextIndex (index, maxLength, inputs.length);

        // Set the print here everything looks fine
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(allList.get(i)));
    }

    // However, if you pit it here to check if you get the correct ArrayList, problem happens
    //for (int g = 0; g < total; g++)
        //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(allList.get(g)));
```

Another part is:

```
// Get the index of the next possible combination
public static int[] nextIndex (int[] index, int maxLength, int siZe)
{   
    for (int i = (maxLength - 1); i > 0; i--)
    {
            if (index[i] == (siZe - 1))
            {
                index[i] = 0;
                if(index[i-1] == (siZe - 1)){
                    continue;
                }
                    index[i - 1]++;
                    break;
            }else{
            index[i]++;
            break;
            }

    }
```

The idea of this part of my program is to generate all possible combinations (with replacement) from the String array "inputs" and store the combinations into an overall ArrayList. Printing them out just my habit to check whether each step is correct or not.

The wrong output that I keep getting (just part of the output):

```
[6, 6, 6, 6]
[6, 6, 6, 6]
[6, 6, 6, 6]
[6, 6, 6, 6]
[6, 6, 6, 6]
[6, 6, 6, 6]
```

The correct output that I want to get:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 2]
[1, 1, 1, 3]
[1, 1, 1, 4]
[1, 1, 1, 5]
[1, 1, 1, 6]
```

Comment: Time to learn to use a debugger for step-by-step execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating the `subSets` Array outside your `for` loop and hence everything in the list is referring to the last updated `subSets` object i.e. `[6, 6, 6, 6]`. You are adding the same object to your list again and again and hence it will update the latest values at all the places in your list.

Move it inside your `for` loop as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < total; i++)
{
    /* Move It Here */
    String[] subSets = new String[maxLength];
    for (int j = 0; j < maxLength; j++)
    {
        subSets[j] = inputs[index[j]];
    }
    allList.add(subSets);
    if (i != (total - 1))
        index = nextIndex (index, maxLength, inputs.length);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. It works.  I thought inside of the nested for loop, the array will be updated. I don't really get how could the last permutation can take over all the other positions in the ArrayList? Do you mean that java knows that I am adding the same object, so it will update all of them? Thanks!

Comment: @Mr. Ting Yes. JAVA Knows! :) As I have said above, if you are creating your object outside the loop then you are adding the same object (same reference) to your list again and again. It points to the same system memory location and hence if the object value is updated then it will be reflected to all the places. Last value which is being updated is `[6, 6, 6, 6]`, when this value is updated in memory it gets reflected everywhere throughout the list because all your list items are holding the same object.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating the subsets array just outside the for loops, so you are always updating the same array. this is the reason why, at the end you get the last permutation.
move the "String[] subSets = new String[maxLength];" just inside the for loop related to "i"

`for (int i = 0; i < total; i++)
    {
    //create the new array here
    String[] subSets = new String[maxLength];
    ...
    }`

and you will get the right output:

`1296
    [1, 1, 1, 1]
    [1, 1, 1, 2]
    [1, 1, 1, 3]
    [1, 1, 1, 4]
    [1, 1, 1, 5]
    .....
    [6, 6, 6, 4]
    [6, 6, 6, 5]
    [6, 6, 6, 6]`

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. This did work for me. However, I still quite don't understand why it doesn't work if I create it outside of the loop? Could you explain a little bit more? Because I thought inside of the nested for loop, the array will be updated.

Comment: And one more question, how could the last permutation can take over all the other positions in the ArrayList? Thanks!

Comment: @Mr. Ting Because if you are creating it outside the loop then you are adding the same object to your list again and again. It points to the same system memory location and hence if the value is updated then it will be reflected to all the places. Last value which is being updated is `[6, 6, 6, 6]`, when this value is updated in memory it gets reflected everywhere throughout the list because all your list items are holding the same object.

Comment: Oh, I get it. Thank you so much!

Comment: thanks @user2004685 for extending my short explanation.